# 'function' is not a py.js object - OpenERP

Tags: odoo, typeerror

I am getting the following error in OpenERP:

TypeError: 'function' is not a py.js object

I have made duplicates of the account.invoice and account.invoice.line by the names sgs.invoice and sgs.invoice.line. i am copying data from account.invoice and account.invoice.line to the duplicate tables. But when I try to edit the data in sgs.invoice.line, I get the above error on clicking any many2one field or any text field having on_change method associated with it. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referenced in the context to one field that doesn't exist for example:

```
<field name="invoice_line" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" context="{'type': type}">
```

And the field:

```
<field name="type"/>
```

doesn't exist in the master table.